# MariaDB Galera Cluster : Second node not coming up

Tags: mariadb, galera

Installing MariaDB Galera cluster 10.0.35 on two nodes on RHEL 7.5.
I am able to bring up first node successfully.However getting below error when bringing the second node :

180524 23:45:27 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
180524 23:45:27 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '173.36.55.164' --datadir '/mysql/product/'   --parent '20955' --binlog '/mysql/product/mysql-bin' '
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: rsync|173.36.55.164:4444/rsync_sst
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 7 (3, 2)
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 5, protocol version: 3
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
180524 23:45:28 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (3b95c41c-5fa2-11e8-8d53-2a74c875a219): 1 (Operation not permitted)
         at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():482. IST will be unavailable.
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: Member 1.0 (vm-srin-006) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (vm-pahc-00b)(SYNCED) as donor.
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 5)
180524 23:45:28 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
180524 23:45:28 [Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (vm-pahc-00b): State transfer to 1.0 (vm-srin-006) failed: -255 (Unknown error 255)
180524 23:45:28 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():731: Will never receive state. Need to abort.

Appreciate any help to resolve this.

Thanks,
Vijay

PS : Resolved the issue.
Issue was related port.After opening the all the ports,second and third nodes were able to join the cluster.
Though I am not sure which all ports needs to open.
Two ports which I identified were : 3360 and 4567

I dont see any documents where it mentions which all ports needs to be opened.
Appreciate if any one has  information on the same.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. 
Execute the following command on the node that is not coming up:

mysqld --wsrep-recover

Then start mysql server asusal (e.g. systemctl start mysql)

This blog may be of help:
https://severalnines.com/blog/how-bootstrap-mysqlmariadb-galera-cluster